# Flush operation for Java non-blocking socket

Tags: java, sockets, networking, nonblocking

In normal blocking socket, I can use Socket.getOutputStream().flush() to partly control when to send out a TCP packet. Is there an equivalent operation for SocketChannel?

Edit: My guess is that every time I call SocketChannel.write(ByteBuffer src), at least one individual packet will be sent, even the buffer has only 1 byte(assume Nagle is off), am I right?

Edit: package -> packet, sorry for wrong spelling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I noted recently Socket.getOutputStream().flush() does nothing in Sun's JDK 6.

However, there is no guarentee that write() will send one packet (not package) it could send more or less.  All you know is it has been passed to the OS to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could write something like

```
while (buf.hasRemaining()) {
    socketChan.write(buf);
}
```

Perhaps there is a better solution.